# How can I show image in flutter by file without path?

Tags: flutter, image, file, flutter-image, flutter-js

I want to show the image in flutter, but I have a file just in two shapes (file - base64).

Comment: can you explain exactly why show image with two shape and where use it?you can use singe line if statement and for exmaple show your image in web use this format and when show in phone use other that format

Comment: I have this image file in the js file and I want to move it to flutter and show it.
I moved it, but I want to the right way to show it.
I mean when I said I have two shapes because I can use Image.file or Image.memory in a flutter.
Thanks @ImanYarahmadi